# How can I remove the toolbar without removing the theme

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to remove my app action bar but when I tried it using this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

My whole app changed to sort of dark gray (pics attached)

[image: before]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the xml of the items in this recycler view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it,s so easy in MainActivity put this line `getSupportActionBar().hide();`